# IndexError: index out of range: on opning xls in xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have a rather niche problem which I just can't get to the bottom of.

I receive xls files from a third party which are proving troublesome to parse in xlrd - whenever I load them in I get the error:

```
--> 312     options = BYTES_ORD(data[pos])
    313     pos += 1
    314     phonetic = options & 0x04

IndexError: index out of range
```

Upon opening them in Excel I receive the error:

```
PROTECTED VIEW: Office has detected a problem with this file, editing it may harm your computer
```

But the file actually opens, and upon resaving it, in xlsx format, it then parses.

I can not even to begin to diagnose what the issue is however...

Full traceback:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-0e9a3a712fe6> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 xlrd.open_workbook('bnp.xls')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    155         formatting_info=formatting_info,
    156         on_demand=on_demand,
--> 157         ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
    158     )
    159     return bk

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py in open_workbook_xls(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    115                 bk.on_demand = on_demand = False
    116         else:
--> 117             bk.parse_globals()
    118             bk._sheet_list = [None for sh in bk._sheet_names]
    119             if not on_demand:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py in parse_globals(self)
   1231                 self.handle_sheethdr(data)
   1232             elif rc == XL_SUPBOOK:
-> 1233                 self.handle_supbook(data)
   1234             elif rc == XL_NAME:
   1235                 self.handle_name(data)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py in handle_supbook(self, data)
   1105             if blah: print("SUPBOOK[%d]: add-in functions" % sbn, file=self.logfile)
   1106             return
-> 1107         url, pos = unpack_unicode_update_pos(data, 2, lenlen=2)
   1108         if num_sheets == 0:
   1109             self._supbook_types[-1] = SUPBOOK_DDEOLE

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/biffh.py in unpack_unicode_update_pos(data, pos, lenlen, known_len)
    310         # Zero-length string with no options byte
    311         return (UNICODE_LITERAL(""), pos)
--> 312     options = BYTES_ORD(data[pos])
    313     pos += 1
    314     phonetic = options & 0x04

IndexError: index out of range
```

Comment: It seems that either `pos` is not a valid index for `data`, or the result is not a valid index for something else inside `BYTES_ORD`. We can’t say more without seeing the relevant code you are using and the full error traceback, and ideally a sample input file.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the code is as simple as:
```xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)```
It's commercially sensitive, I'll see if I can remove data and resave keeping the error intact.

When I try and turn logging on in xlrd it crashes out before a log can be saved...

Comment: @mkrieger1 the full traceback is in the original